# ubuntu upstart for service with multiple daemons

Tags: upstart

my service is a group of "multiple" daemons. I need to integrate it with upstart to be started during the bootup. The problem is that I need to restart the service when any of the daemons dies abruptly. can i do it with one .conf script or do  i need mutiple .conf scripts for this. 
pls advise. 
Thanks in advance, 
-rk

Answer (score 0):

If all of your daemons play nicely with "respawn" SIGTERMs then you could just incorporate them into one wrapper script. From [Upstart Respawning](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#respawn):

`One situation where it may seem like respawn should be avoided, is when a daemon doesn't respond well to SIGTERM for stopping it. You may believe that you need to send the service its shutdown command without upstart being involved, and therefore, you don't want to use respawn because upstart will keep trying to start your service back up when you told it to shutdown.`

`However, the appopriate way to handle that situation is a pre-stop which runs this shutdown command. Since the job's goal will already be 'stop' when a pre-stop is run, you can shutdown the process through any means, and the process won't be respawned (even with the respawn stanza).`